# how to set the url and parameter of a .php file using postman for webservices?

Tags: php, web-services, url

I'm new to PHP web services, I just made file which is 
**view/html/register_user.html** 
like this

```
`
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required=""><span id="msg1"></span><br>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
email: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required=""><span id="msg2"></span><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
password: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required=""><span id="msg3"></span><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
type: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" id="type" required=""><span id="msg4"></span><br>
</div>
<input id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // click on button submit
    $("#submit").on('click', function(){
     var name = $('#name').val();
     var email = $('#email').val();
    var password =$('#password').val();
    var type =$('#type').val();

    if(name=="" || name==null){

          $('#msg1').text("please enter name");

    }

    if(email=="" || email==null){

         $('#msg2').text("plese enter email");

    }

     if(password=="" || password==null){

          $("#msg3").text("please insert password");

    }

     if(type=="" || type==null){

          $("#msg4").text("please insert type");

    }
    else{


            // send ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/view/webservices/register_user.php', 
                type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
                dataType : 'json', // data type
                data : $("#form").serialize(), // post data || get data
                success : function(result,status) {

                    // you can see the result from the console
                    // tab of the developer tools
                alert("data has been added:  "+result +status);
                //alert(document.getElementById("form").value);

                document.getElementById("form").reset(); 
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            });
        }
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

which is going to another page **view/webservices/register_user.ph**p

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept'); ?>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT'); ?>
<?php 
include_once('../configdb.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$name= $_POST['name'];
$email =$_POST['email'] ;
$password=$_POST['password'];
$type =$_POST['type'] ;

$sql="INSERT INTO users(name,email,password,type) VALUES('$name','$email','$password','$type')";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($query==1){
    $result[] = array("status"=>1);
}
    else{
        $result[]=array("status"=>0);
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($_POST);

?>
```

I want to know how to set the URL which has some response according to input or like how to check via postman application where I can provide URL and its parameter and can get the response in json ? will I have to buy a web host or will it work on localhost?

**UPDATE** Or for making and android application will I need to buy a host or will it work on locally ?

Comment: you can do this in your localhost it self. In post man you can put your url which looks like `http://loclahost/yourProjectName/yourPageName`

Comment: Will it work if i make and android application using php webservies ? will it work locally ?

Comment: I didn't understand you exactly. but i think you are asking that, will android app work if we give our localhost address right ? if so, the answer is no.